# Read from input two values and add them, just using one variable.. possible?

Tags: c++, variables, puzzle

Salute..

Let's see this example:

```
int x,y,s;
cin>>x>>y;
s=x+y;
```

here we have three variables for adding two values..

**Can we do this just with one variable?**

thanks.

Comment: Why? This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Or a (terrible) interview question.

Comment: oh no, neither. maybe the original, but i myself just found this question :)

Comment: @BlackBear: Let us see your way :)

Comment: @Looser: i was thinking about saving a temp value in the stack, but this counts as a local var i guess ; b

Comment: Would this cut it: `int x[ 2 ]; cin >> x[ 0 ] >> x[ 1 ]; x[ 0 ] += x[ 1 ];`?

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca: nice..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about zero variables?

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout <<
    std::accumulate(
      std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
      std::istream_iterator<int>(),
      0) <<
    "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
struct Accumulator {
    int value;
    Accumulator(): value(0) {}
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& ss, Accumulator& acc)
    { int x; ss >> x; acc.value += x; return ss; }
};

int main() {
    Accumulator a;
    std::cin >> a >> a;
    std::cout << "Total is " << a.value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

See how useful abstraction is?

Answer (score 3):

You can cut out one by using the extraction operator twice.

```
int x, s = 0;
cin >> x;
s += x;
cin >> x;
s += x;
```

You could cut that down even more by using a single variable that's twice the size of `int`. I can't believe I am typing this:

```
long long s;
assert(sizeof(int)*2 == sizeof(long long));
cin >> *(int*)(&s);
cin >> *((int*)(&s)+1);
s = (s & 0xffffffff) + ((s >> 32) & 0xffffffff);
```

You're only allowed to do things like this when you absolutely need to do something like store two 32-bit values in a 64-bit register for arcane performance reasons, or the gods will smite you. In such a case you are likely not using the iostream library anyway, but there you go. I'm going to go take a shower to wash the code smell off. I might need some lye.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Very important note, int **is** 16 bit. The code is very, very long. There is a lot of constants. Something like this.

```
int x;
cin >> x;

if (x == -32768) {
    cin >> x;
    x = x - 32768; 
} else if (x == -32767) {
    cin >> x;
    x = x - 32767; 
} else ...
...
} else if (x == -1) {
    cin >> x;
    x = x - 1;
} else if (x == 0) {
    cin >> x;
    x = x;
} else if (x == 1) {
    cin >> x;
    x = x + 1;
} else ...
...
} else if (x == 32766) {
    cin >> x;
    x = x + 32766;
} else {
    cin >> x;
    x = x + 32767;
}
cout << x << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: Come on, at least use a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can cut it down to 2 variables by using `x+=y`

You're not allowed to do anything like `cin<<x<<x+=y` which would be the only way I would know how to cut it down to a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't as long as that variable is an `int`. But why do you want to anyway?

Of course, you can get rid of `s` by `x += y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
        typedef long long int64;

        int64 x;
        cin >> ((int*)(&x))[0] >> ((int*)(&x))[1];
        x = ((int*)(&x))[0] + ((int*)(&x))[1];
        cout << x << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
100 250
```

Output

```
350
```

See yourself at ideone : http://ideone.com/2AmK0

**Note:** I don't know how portable this solution is. But this works with `gcc-4.3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below one would work.....

```
#include<stdio.h>
int x=0;
int getno()
   {
     scanf("%d",&x);
     return x;
   }
int main()
   {
     x=getno()+getno();
     printf("addition of the number is = %d",x);
   }
```